# WPF controls look like WinForms - what settings I'm missing?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, .net-4.0, wpf-controls

I run my WPF application (.Net 4.0) on a server (Microsoft Server 2008 R2 Enterprise - Service Pack 1).

On my desktop machine all the WPF controls look nice. On the server, many of them look really awful, like totally unstyled WinForms controls.

Could you please suggest what kind of configuration is required for a machine in order to show WPF controls properly.

Comment: you need aero theme on server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this has to do with Server 2008 R2's use of the classic theme.

I would check this blog post here: http://www.kennethham.com/wp/2010/11/force-wpf-to-use-windows-7aero-theming-in-classic-mode/

You need to force the application to use Win7/Aero theming.

Comment: This exactly seems to be what is happening here. I am working in a remotely on a Windows 2008 Server R2.